# Cocktail party - audio source separation

Tags: audio, machine-learning, octave, svd

I am trying to solve the "Cocktail Party Problem".

Here is a [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2CD-3WLY8zg&t=) beautifully explaining and solving this problem.

In the video he claims one line of code solved this problem.
So I got my hands on those same audio files he uses in the video [from here](http://cnl.salk.edu/~tewon/Blind/blind_audio.html), and I included the line of code that he uses in the video (line 5), but I get significantly worse results. The code I have basically just outputs the same original mixed audio files, in lower volume.

This is the code I have in Octave:

```
[x1, Fs1] = audioread('mixed1.wav');
[x2, Fs2] = audioread('mixed2.wav');
xx = [x1, x2]';
yy = sqrtm(inv(cov(xx')))*(xx-repmat(mean(xx,2),1,size(xx,2)));
[W,s,v] = svd((repmat(sum(yy.*yy,1),size(yy,1),1).*yy)*yy');
a = W*xx;
audiowrite('refined1.wav', a(1,:), Fs1);
audiowrite('refined2.wav', a(2,:), Fs1);
```

I don't understand why this doesn't work. I mean, he actually shows in the video that it works, maybe not 100% accurate, but it definitely works quite well.

What did I do wrong and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 2):

Here is Octave code demonstrating how to:

1. Mix 2 sound files.
2. Separate them again.

```
# Read original (unmixed) signals.
[o1, Fs1] = audioread('original1.wav');
[o2, Fs2] = audioread('original2.wav');

# Sampling rates Fs1, Fs2 should be equal!

# o Nx2 contains original signals
o = [o1, o2];

# A is a mixing matrix to make a linear combination of the input sounds.
# It can be arbitrarily changed (must be invertible).
A = [.8,.5 ; .1,.4];

# m Nx2 contains mixed signals 
m = o * A;

# Save mixed files
audiowrite('mixed1.wav', m(:, 1), Fs1);
audiowrite('mixed2.wav', m(:, 2), Fs1);

# Uncomment to read your own mixed files.
#[m1, Fs1] = audioread('mymix1.wav');
#[m2, Fs2] = audioread('mymix2.wav');
#m = [m1, m2];

if 0  
    # Precise solution
    # W1 is ideal unmixing matrix
    W1 = inv(A);

    # s Nx2 contains separated signals 
    s = m * W1; 
else
    # Compute W by a magic algo
    # See https://cs.nyu.edu/~roweis/kica.html
    xx = m';

    yy = sqrtm(inv(cov(xx')))*(xx-repmat(mean(xx,2),1,size(xx,2)));
    [W,s,v] = svd((repmat(sum(yy.*yy,1),size(yy,1),1).*yy)*yy');

    ss = W * yy; 

    # Scale down by an empiric value
    s = ss * 0.5;

    # s Nx2 contains separated signals 
    s = s';
end

audiowrite('separated1.wav', s(:, 1), Fs1);
audiowrite('separated2.wav', s(:, 2), Fs1);
```

Unfortunately it does not work with [real audio](https://cnl.salk.edu/~tewon/Blind/blind_audio.html) from 2 microphones.